# Как вывести все найденные строки из цикла

Tags: php

Подскажите новичку пожалуйста, есть файл в нем в каждой строке есть запись каждое значение розделено `#` вместо пробела. Зная росположения пытаюсь получить все найденные записи через `forech` но не знаю как правильно вывести из цикла все полученые результаты.

test.txt

- ftth#00256#alex#202a
- ftpp#0896#corn#005b

---

Код

```
$file= file("test.txt");  
foreach($file as $lin){
    $expl=explode("#",$lin); 
    echo"'$expl[2]',";
} //получаю все значения как и хотел 002560896.
echo $expl[2]; //получаю первое 00256 значение, а как получить все после закрытия foreach }
```

Comment: *"как правильно вывести из цыкла"* --- вы же это делаете на 4-ой строчке кода..... Напишите пример output который вы в итоге хотите сделать ............. P.S. "цИкл" не "цЫкл"

Comment: Все верно в 4 строке я получаю то что нужно но мне нужно получить результат  после } чтоб его можна было вставить  скрипт.   <script>
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
 <? echo $expl[2]; ?>
   'Google'
    ];
    $( '#tags' ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
  </script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если искомое значение по индексу 2, то надо все значения положить в отдельный массив. Для этого:

- **Перед началом цикла** заводим переменную, например `$names = [];`
- **Внутри цикла** в этот массив складываем необходимые данные.
- **За циклом** проверить данные можно например через `print_r`. Можно сделать цельную строку через `$implodedNames = implode(',', $names);` и т.д.

Comment: $file= file("test.txt");  
foreach($file as $lin){
    $expl=explode("#",$lin); 
    echo"'$expl[2]',";
      $imp = implode(',', $expl[2]);}
print_r($imp);

Comment: Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed

Comment: Прочитай ответ еще раз. Там прям четко написано в какой момент делать `implode`.

Comment: Если можно покажите на моем коде ато я не понимаю очем речь. Меня никто не учил и спросить неукого я учусь на примерах и своих ошибках.

Comment: Вот тебе шаблончик с подсказками https://3v4l.org/VBb72

Comment: я пробовал за циклом  } $imp = implode(',', $expl[2]); print_r($imp); ошибка таже.

Comment: Спасибо всем большое понял.

Comment: @Serg_rv если ответ помог - галочку рядом с ним тык)